# "State: Shared" on some folders in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing

What does *State: Shared* mean? I have it on Windows, Program Files, Users and PerfLog folders on my C: drive. I am running Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: I don't see that lable in explorer.exe, but It appears to mean that those folders are shared over the network, likely as an Administrative share. run `net share` in an Administrator command prompt, and you can see all the administrative and user shares. Note that not all administrative shares are for file sharing with other hosts, so be careful if you choose to disable individual shares.

Answer (score 3):

Those folders are shared is some fashion, either visibly (such as the `Users` folder through the `File and Printer sharing` function) or through a [hidden admin "$" share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share).  You can utilize a GUI to see what is shared on your machine through the following method:

1. Hold <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Type `fsmgmt.msc` and right-click to `Run as administrator`
3. When the `Shared Folders` window opens highlight the `Shares` folder on the upper-left to display your computer's shared resources on the right:

[image: Shared Folders]

Answer (score 0):

If you disable the service called server in your computer **services.msc**. You will have them stated shared but will not be accessed by any other person or system. As above fsmgmt.msc service does not work properly with the service **server** disabled.

This share is called SMB and will work over the local network. For most that share stuff in a remote environment, they risk their files being available to anyone.

[image]